# Can I swap a MLCC for a tantalum capacitor?

Tags: capacitor

Can anyone tell me if this (RadioShack)
10uF 16V 20% Dipped Tantalum Capacitor

is a suitable replacement for (Mouser)
Multilayer Ceramic Capacitors MLCC - Leaded 10uF 6.3volts X5R 10% 5.0mm L/S ?

Comment: It depends on what purpose it's being put to. Generally no, since the tantalum is polarised and the MLCC isn't.

Comment: A schematic might be helpful.

Comment: Also ESR/ESL of a radioshack tantalum cap will be way higher than that of a MLCC.

Comment: Tants don't handle high-current surges very well.

Comment: By the way, when subjected to reversed voltage and significant amount of current, a tantalum capacitor can literally burst into flame like a match head. Which is how a dipped tantalum cap looks like.

Comment: The answer is "*No.  With the level of detail provided by the O.P. so far, nobody cal tell.*"

Answer (score 5):

Without specific information on a particular appliction, the only possible answer is "no".

For one thing tantalum capacitors are polarized whereas the ceramic is not.  The tantalum will also have significantly higer ESR, lower ripple current tolerance, lower temperature tolerance, and possibly much worse consequences if excessive voltage or reverse voltage is applied.

If you know how the capacitor will be used and stresses it will be subject to, then possibly the tantalum could be used as a replacement.  You haven't given us any such specifics, and in the general case you certainly can't replace the ceramic with a tantalum, so the answer is still "no".